# Serial.println not outputting

Tags: analogread, arduino-micro, genuine

I ran the following really simple code on my micro and the monitor is just blank, not displaying any zeroes or anything and the Tx light isn't lighting up. I haven't used analog inputs much so I don't know what could be causing this. Can anyone help? Thanks, here's the code

```
int sensePin = 0;
void setup() {
    analogReference(DEFAULT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(analogRead(sensePin));
  delay(500);

}
```

Comment: What board are you using? What IDE version? What operating system?

Comment: The arduino micro, on windows 8, IDE version 1.0.5

Comment: Genuine micro? OR chinese clone?

Comment: Its genuine as far as I know

Comment: Have you tried programming the Blink sketch to the board?

Comment: Might need a "while (!Serial);" after "Serial.begin(9600);" in setup().

Comment: Definitely need that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to no ouput, and suspecting your data source is to replace the data source with a constant value or a string until you get that problem sorted, and then go back to your data source and debug that if necessary.

That said, I don't see any issue with you trying to print the output of an analog read. Obviously you should get *something*, even if it's just a single zero on each line, twice a second.

- Is your monitor the Arduino built-in monitor?
- Is it set to 9600 baud, as you've set your output rate in the program?
- Is there anything else connected to the Tx pin, Pin-1 (Arduino numbering, not chip numbering)?
- There were no error messages from the compiler or loader, right? (The libraries, bless-'em, always get a few warnings; unfortunately we have to ignore those).
- You've no reason to believe the Arduino is other than 100% good?